# File is not a constructor issue in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to crop image using the angular library "ngx-image-cropper". Thereafter cropping, I am getting an image in the base64 format so I want to convert that image to file format. I am using the following code to convert base64 string to BLOB and then BLOB to file format.

```
fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = event;
  }

  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    var result = this.b64toBlob(this.croppedImage);

    var file = new File([result], 'uploaded_file.jpg', {type: 'image/jpeg', lastModified: Date.now()});
}

b64toBlob(dataURI) {

    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

But on BLOB to file conversion I am getting error "ERROR TypeError: File is not a constructor". What should I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I have fixed it after removing the File type from the component variable.

```
public imageFile: File = null;
```

The solution works for me:

```
public imageFile = null;
```